# Removing stuck water pump - GM Corsa B

Tags: water-pump, gm, corsa

I have a GM Corsa 1.0 MPFI (Brazillian version of the Opel Corsa B) and today I started replacing some parts, including the water pump. I had heard from other owners and mechanics that sometimes this water pump gets stuck because of rust and it's really hard to remove, requiring that you "hammer" it out. With me it wasn't different. The water pump doesn't move out when I pull it with my hand.

Below is an image of a the working area, not from my car but probably the same model. The water pump is right below the alternator:

[image: Bomba Dágua]

Any tips on how to remove it? Maybe other cars have similar issues with rusted water pumps. Even if I should use brute force, how should I hit the pump and where? I even thought about making something similar to a pulley remover and try to pull it out from the small gear, but I don't think it would handle the force.

Comment: In the picture, you can see three bolts holding the water pump in (there are flat washers on them doing the deed) ... I'm hoping you removed these?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 The picture was just to give an idea of how my water pump looks like. I had removed the bolts, though one of them was seized and gave me moments of true frustration and despair :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have removed the three bolts surrounding the water pump, and the ultimate goal is to replace the water pump with a new one, just use a hammer and hit the water pump pulley. It should pop right off. You are not worried about the pump itself, because it is getting replaced. There should be a gasket residually holding the pump in place. You just need to break the pump free of this. Besides the gasket, it should be flat on flat, meaning there is nothing there to get damaged. Ensure you clean the block side off so you'll have a clean mating surface for the new gasket with the new pump.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to hammer it out, I suggest a rubber mallet. With a metal hammer the force of impact may transfer through the water pump and break other parts you are not intending to replace.

Alternatively, look for a spot where you can insert a long pry bar (e.g. something that looks like [https://www.amazon.com/4-Piece-Mechanic-Dicfeos-Thicker-Strike/dp/B07BKVWXWQ](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07BKVWXWQ))  and pry the water pump off the block. Prior to using the pry bar tape its end with electrical or painter's tape, whatever happens to be convenient.

Another approach is take a very long flat head screwdriver, put it on various edges of the water pump and *gently* tap it with a hammer.

Comment: I upvoted your answer because it's good as well. Trying to make a lever with the screwdriver didn't work very well for me, I was feeling I'd either break the screwdriver or mark the block while the pump was solid still. Maybe I was doing it wrong though, I've seem videos of it being removed that way. For me, laying a piece of wood on top of the pulley and hammering it was what did the trick.